# Typescript property error and logic question

Tags: typescript, logic

I started with typescript today, and is unsure how to correct this error, or if it is even good practice. I have a basic function which displays the name when a user inputs his name.

However, the problem is that when I have returned the result from the function, and want to console log it, I obviously get a "property does not exist on X" error because the two objects have different keys and it throws a typescript error.

```
interface greetObject {
  text: string
}
interface errorObject {
  errorText: string,
}

 const results: greetObject | errorObject = await callFetch(speechInput.value);
 console.log(results.text || results.errorText)
```

**So my question is, how do I solve this?**

I have tried and found two ways, but none of them seems good practice.

1: I simply change the type to any (But doesn't that defeat the whole point with typescript?)

```
const results: any = await callFetch(speechInput.value);
```

2: I change/edit the interface (Seems like it could cause more problem in the long run)

```
interface greetObject {
  [key: string]: string,
  text: string
}
interface errorObject {
  [key: string]: string,
  errorText: string
}
```

**All of the code:**

```
interface greetObject {
  text: string
}
interface errorObject {
  errorText: string,
}

async function callFetch(greeting: string): Promise < greetObject | errorObject > {
  try {
    return <greetObject > {text: greeting};
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return <errorObject > {
      errorText: "there was an error"
    }
  }
}

submitButton.addEventListener("click", async (e: MouseEvent) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const results: greetObject | errorObject = await callFetch(speechInput.value);
  console.log(results.text || results.errorText)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, I needed to use a guard with the "in" operator because it was two objects.

```
console.log("text" in results ? results.text : results.errorText)
```